# automatically post message on own facebook with new policy

Tags: facebook-graph-api, token

I want to use the FacebookClient to post a message on my own site. I need to have a user access token (no expiration). That's possible with the Grpah API explorer. The token need the publish_pages en manage_pages permission.

But since 1 may it is not possible anymore to get this permission without review. I understand that a review is needed now when anyone has to post on my business facebook, but in my case, only I need to post the message. How can I get this without reviewing?

Comment: there are no user tokens without expiration. and for posting on YOUR page (with a PAGE token, not a user token), you should not need review.

Comment: I already tried with a Page token but the exception says: Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission


I used this code:
FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
messagePost.message = message;
var result = facebookClient.Post("/" + pageid + "/feed", messagePost);